# Как получить доступ к картинке background button в SwiftUI?

Tags: swift

Пытаюсь переписать приложение в SwiftUI. До этого было сделано в storyboard. В приложении реализован ротатор баннеров с помощью button. Вот код:
'''

```
import UIKit

class NavigteViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let images = [UIImage(named: "Agrokomplexshop"), UIImage(named: "allradru"), UIImage(named: "Baggins"), UIImage(named: "Bestwatch"), UIImage(named: "Blackwoodbag"), UIImage(named: "CDEK"), UIImage(named: "Credit7RU"), UIImage(named: "cvetDivanov"), UIImage(named: "europamarket"), UIImage(named: "fitstars"), UIImage(named: "growfood"), UIImage(named: "Iskussnica"), UIImage(named: "kolesaDarom"), UIImage(named: "Letbefit"), UIImage(named: "LevelKitchen"), UIImage(named: "MadWave"), UIImage(named: "Mealjoyru"), UIImage(named: "MoskovskayaMehovayaKompaniya"), UIImage(named: "NFONorwegianFishOil"), UIImage(named: "OKBeauty"), UIImage(named: "Petrolplus"), UIImage(named: "Pichshop"), UIImage(named: "Pizzaallo"), UIImage(named: "playtoday"), UIImage(named: "Pokrishka"), UIImage(named: "Polis812RU"), UIImage(named: "ProfmaxPro"), UIImage(named: "Randewoo"), UIImage(named: "RenessansJiznRU"), UIImage(named: "rerooms"), UIImage(named: "Rockyshop"), UIImage(named: "sbermarket"), UIImage(named: "Shopneoline"), UIImage(named: "Smallcitysu"), UIImage(named: "Smartwaytoday"), UIImage(named: "sohoshop"), UIImage(named: "Sprinthost"), UIImage(named: "SuperStepRU"), UIImage(named: "TheFurnish"), UIImage(named: "ugindoma"), UIImage(named: "VKMuzika"), UIImage(named: "Vprokru"), UIImage(named: "YandexBuisnessRU"), UIImage(named: "yandexgodlyabiznesa"), UIImage(named: "zaochnik"), UIImage(named: "ZettaStrhovanieRU"), UIImage(named: "zoomag"), UIImage(named: "zooptorgrf"), UIImage(named: "AlfaBankCreditnieKartiRU"), UIImage(named: "aliexpress"), UIImage(named: "alter"), UIImage(named: "autoall"), UIImage(named: "autopiter"), UIImage(named: "Bbcream"), UIImage(named: "calltouch"), UIImage(named: "cantra"), UIImage(named: "CherehapaRU"), UIImage(named: "GeekBrains"), UIImage(named: "productstar"), UIImage(named: "Promomegafitpro"), UIImage(named: "puzzlemovies"), UIImage(named: "RBKPro"), UIImage(named: "skypro"), UIImage(named: "Tetrikaschool"), UIImage(named: "Ukassa"), UIImage(named: "Vipfish"), UIImage(named: "YESEducationGroup")]
        
        let imag = images.randomElement()
        
        bunnerImageBackground.setImage((imag as! UIImage) , for: .normal)
    }
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var bunnerImageBackground: UIButton!
    
    
    
    @IBAction func bunner(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let imagesfor = [UIImage(named: "Agrokomplexshop"), UIImage(named: "allradru"), UIImage(named: "Baggins"), UIImage(named: "Bestwatch"), UIImage(named: "Blackwoodbag"), UIImage(named: "CDEK"), UIImage(named: "Credit7RU"), UIImage(named: "cvetDivanov"), UIImage(named: "europamarket"), UIImage(named: "fitstars"), UIImage(named: "growfood"), UIImage(named: "Iskussnica"), UIImage(named: "kolesaDarom"), UIImage(named: "Letbefit"), UIImage(named: "LevelKitchen"), UIImage(named: "MadWave"), UIImage(named: "Mealjoyru"), UIImage(named: "MoskovskayaMehovayaKompaniya"), UIImage(named: "NFONorwegianFishOil"), UIImage(named: "OKBeauty"), UIImage(named: "Petrolplus"), UIImage(named: "Pichshop"), UIImage(named: "Pizzaallo"), UIImage(named: "playtoday"), UIImage(named: "Pokrishka"), UIImage(named: "Polis812RU"), UIImage(named: "ProfmaxPro"), UIImage(named: "Randewoo"), UIImage(named: "RenessansJiznRU"), UIImage(named: "rerooms"), UIImage(named: "Rocky-shop"), UIImage(named: "sbermarket"), UIImage(named: "Shopneoline"), UIImage(named: "Smallcitysu"), UIImage(named: "Smartwaytoday"), UIImage(named: "sohoshop"), UIImage(named: "Sprinthost"), UIImage(named: "SuperStepRU"), UIImage(named: "TheFurnish"), UIImage(named: "ugindoma"), UIImage(named: "VKMuzika"), UIImage(named: "Vprokru"), UIImage(named: "YandexBuisnessRU"), UIImage(named: "yandexgodlyabiznesa"), UIImage(named: "zaochnik"), UIImage(named: "ZettaStrhovanieRU"), UIImage(named: "zoomag"), UIImage(named: "zooptorgrf"), UIImage(named: "AlfaBankCreditnieKartiRU"), UIImage(named: "aliexpress"), UIImage(named: "alter"), UIImage(named: "autoall"), UIImage(named: "autopiter"), UIImage(named: "Bbcream"), UIImage(named: "calltouch"), UIImage(named: "cantra"), UIImage(named: "CherehapaRU"), UIImage(named: "GeekBrains"), UIImage(named: "productstar"), UIImage(named: "Promomegafitpro"), UIImage(named: "puzzlemovies"), UIImage(named: "RBKPro"), UIImage(named: "skypro"), UIImage(named: "Tetrikaschool"), UIImage(named: "Ukassa"), UIImage(named: "Vipfish"), UIImage(named: "YESEducationGroup")]
        
        
        switch bunnerImageBackground.currentImage {
            
        case imagesfor[0]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/lkj8u73nnd31225e5a7704cb4947eb/")!)
        case imagesfor[1]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/elgf718etq31225e5a770e020ad620/?erid=LatgBUcjU")!)
        case imagesfor[2]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/m33u5flihp31225e5a7787b20ecef3/?erid=LatgBgkRu")!)
        case imagesfor[3]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/7d074b20eb31225e5a7777d7343c30/?erid=LatgBiNsP")!)
        case imagesfor[4]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/n90gqfg8zz31225e5a7768b0e348e3/?erid=LatgBs8Xq")!)
        case imagesfor[5]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/8m5m8022me31225e5a77fa1399d1cb/")!)
        case imagesfor[6]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/vojb18n6gs31225e5a7796bf0d7973/?erid=LatgBnShk")!)
        case imagesfor[7]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/67570bafb631225e5a7766146bcf1d/")!)
        case imagesfor[8]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/yh7dxsl4ze31225e5a770d5c628f32/?erid=LatgBk5GN")!)
        case imagesfor[9]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/lcz5l7shqa31225e5a77253f07e8f6/")!)
        case imagesfor[10]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/36wusytszy31225e5a77aeb982cd0a/")!)
        case imagesfor[11]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/er5wwbo0j631225e5a77f665c6f820/")!)
        case imagesfor[12]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/phemb8m2uc31225e5a77ccd85565ce/?erid=LatgCAysS")!)
        case imagesfor[13]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/qm29jzxwek31225e5a77fcd3300043/")!)
        case imagesfor[14]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/u7cz7332nc31225e5a77738d825a2a/")!)
        case imagesfor[15]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/02ocqj6mtr31225e5a7702f7474c98/?erid=LatgBxmTS")!)
        case imagesfor[16]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/ml2h339a7u31225e5a77c9dd5f6bbc/")!)
        case imagesfor[17]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/06d83a456331225e5a77c6abdc5353/")!)
        case imagesfor[18]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/l604dr7c1e31225e5a779c176d7edf/?erid=LatgBome6")!)
        case imagesfor[19]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/nl23vc8ifb31225e5a7753b0491767/?erid=LatgBpT4S")!)
        case imagesfor[20]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/ib927vcr1x31225e5a77fdbdccbe6f/?erid=LatgBxrwE")!)
        case imagesfor[21]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/balo8rex4231225e5a77a28df5fc31/?erid=LatgC9HFD")!)
        case imagesfor[22]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/bgi1r32ntf31225e5a77b0f1f587ba/")!)
        case imagesfor[23]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/ibbrr5pyi831225e5a7778ec4c4caa/")!)
        case imagesfor[24]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/bw09hq1psa31225e5a77729032ae9b/?erid=LatgBtona")!)
        case imagesfor[25]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/m7xuhz7ysw31225e5a77440db5965d/")!)
        case imagesfor[26]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/d2y1qd8flb31225e5a7739152ee3f6/?erid=LatgBhUb7")!)
        case imagesfor[27]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/efixkgr4c431225e5a770dd11956d5/")!)
        case imagesfor[28]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/9qw2p1opbr31225e5a77e76cad6e67/?erid=LatgBgjtz")!)
        case imagesfor[29]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/5nilvc2n6731225e5a77592052c97a/?erid=LatgBbjCK")!)
        case imagesfor[30]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/lrpvclu24w31225e5a77be166c0a8b/?erid=LatgBeihm")!)
        case imagesfor[31]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/ugldybr34d31225e5a77326cfdd537/?erid=LatgBYJCD")!)
        case imagesfor[32]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/pi8gje4m1p31225e5a771c454c946b/?erid=LatgBso7Y")!)
        case imagesfor[33]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/vwrmyws33j31225e5a77d720df3727/?erid=LatgBnrbd")!)
        case imagesfor[34]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/c2jesykfil31225e5a7792877be4a1/?erid=LatgCB1Es")!)
        case imagesfor[35]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/x5npm7rr8e31225e5a77e6dc21c9f7/")!)
        case imagesfor[36]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/mxmtlx74bh31225e5a77b183dfeeb8/?erid=LatgByErP")!)
        case imagesfor[37]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/enml32rwhr31225e5a77a814938f71/?erid=LatgBXe4u")!)
        case imagesfor[38]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/e119380ec031225e5a7775922924c2/?erid=LatgBVe6K")!)
        case imagesfor[39]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/5ypaik84gp31225e5a77069ee805e1/?erid=LatgBVKg8")!)
        case imagesfor[40]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/dnezl2xu4131225e5a77af54ab86e0/")!)
        case imagesfor[41]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/paesexo5wj31225e5a77aa88a5b1cc/")!)
        case imagesfor[42]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/tsur35yw0t31225e5a77ff277dce71/")!)
        case imagesfor[43]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/kzlcevsny831225e5a7784814a437b/")!)
        case imagesfor[44]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/sk55otxguo31225e5a776853a97b34/?erid=LatgBb6k3")!)
        case imagesfor[45]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/27wmm2ciw331225e5a774d3555d70b/?erid=LatgBTy98")!)
        case imagesfor[46]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/m7bdjiij7e31225e5a7745912f3e2d/?erid=LatgCAHzf")!)
        case imagesfor[47]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/rvcnriueyx31225e5a77e22b63c9b7/?erid=LatgC9HKd")!)
        case imagesfor[48]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/i352cbwpfv31225e5a771cb5598fff/")!)
        case imagesfor[49]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://alitems.co/g/vv3q4oey1v31225e5a77b6d1781017/")!)
        case imagesfor[50]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/fxysja9qse31225e5a776704bcdbc1/?erid=LatgC1bqD")!)
        case imagesfor[51]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/5rermd1rb531225e5a77aeed5c54e0/?erid=LatgBk8mS")!)
        case imagesfor[52]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/1hedtmqch531225e5a771423f7dae0/?erid=LatgBpn1Q")!)
        case imagesfor[53]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/9l1uizc2km31225e5a771bd767fd6d/?erid=LatgBYK7C")!)
        case imagesfor[54]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/y3x3cfffmv31225e5a77f6ebb01ee1/?erid=LatgC3YPC")!)
        case imagesfor[55]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/ezmwtz3pov31225e5a7785aed9e6f6/?erid=LatgBaf2A")!)
        case imagesfor[56]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/2ey5h355qu31225e5a771e9ee21cc3/?erid=LatgBpnvS")!)
        case imagesfor[57]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/k3dfvevwit31225e5a7765a37ca03d/")!)
        case imagesfor[58]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/t9pnpumx6q31225e5a775e445e6c7b/?erid=LatgC7JZZ")!)
        case imagesfor[59]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/ehygr1fnh831225e5a77ed7d1ea7c0/?erid=LatgBtjgG")!)
        case imagesfor[60]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/ae4zpznc0i31225e5a7742f9f2178b/?erid=LatgC5CoU")!)
        case imagesfor[61]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/hmgfm467d731225e5a774c86cb021e/?erid=LatgC5eJ7")!)
        case imagesfor[62]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/kpr3e0qpel31225e5a775eaaeb7930/?erid=LatgBtSwH")!)
        case imagesfor[63]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/54h3zonoi631225e5a7794d0e5a27a/")!)
        case imagesfor[64]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/hlif2saueo31225e5a77dff88f55df/")!)
        case imagesfor[65]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/lqb6l7197z31225e5a7794cf89477e/")!)
        case imagesfor[66]:
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/tfogdtvvuf31225e5a772019e44728/")!)
         default:
            break
            
        }
       
        
    }
    
}
```

'''
Как теперь реализовать его в SwiftUI? Одну часть я сделал, чтобы при загрузке кнопки background картинка была рандомной. Для этого создал отдельный файл с таким кодом:
'''

```
import SwiftUI
let images = [
Image("Agrokomplexshop"), Image("allradru"), Image("Baggins"), Image("Bestwatch"), Image("Blackwoodbag"), Image("CDEK"), Image("Credit7RU"), Image("cvetDivanov"), Image("europamarket"), Image("fitstars"), Image("growfood"), Image("Iskussnica"), Image("kolesaDarom"), Image("Letbefit"), Image("LevelKitchen"), Image("MadWave"), Image("Mealjoyru"), Image("MoskovskayaMehovayaKompaniya"), Image("NFONorwegianFishOil"), Image("OKBeauty"), Image("Petrolplus"), Image("Pichshop"), Image("Pizzaallo"), Image("playtoday"), Image("Pokrishka"), Image("Polis812RU"), Image("ProfmaxPro"), Image("Randewoo"), Image("RenessansJiznRU"), Image("rerooms"), Image("Rockyshop"), Image("sbermarket"), Image("Shopneoline"), Image("Smallcitysu"), Image("Smartwaytoday"), Image("sohoshop"), Image("Sprinthost"), Image("SuperStepRU"), Image("TheFurnish"), Image("ugindoma"), Image("VKMuzika"), Image("Vprokru"), Image("YandexBuisnessRU"), Image("yandexgodlyabiznesa"), Image("zaochnik"), Image("ZettaStrhovanieRU"), Image("zoomag"), Image("zooptorgrf"), Image("AlfaBankCreditnieKartiRU"), Image("aliexpress"), Image("alter"), Image("autoall"), Image("autopiter"), Image("Bbcream"), Image("calltouch"), Image("cantra"), Image("CherehapaRU"), Image("GeekBrains"), Image("productstar"), Image("Promomegafitpro"), Image("puzzlemovies"), Image("RBKPro"), Image("skypro"), Image("Tetrikaschool"), Image("Ukassa"), Image("Vipfish"), Image("YESEducationGroup")]

let imag = images.randomElement()

struct BunnerButton: ButtonStyle {
   
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
        imag!
        .renderingMode(.original)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 38)
    }
}
```

'''
И добавил стиль в кнопку:
'''

```
Button("Реклама") {
            //action
           
            
        }
        .buttonStyle(BunnerButton())
```

'''
А вот реализовать action не понимаю как. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так, например:

```
import SwiftUI

let files = [
    ["image" : "Agrokomplexshop", "url"   : "https://aflink.ru/g/lkj8u73nnd31225e5a7704cb4947eb/"],
    ["image" : "allradru",        "url"   : "https://aflink.ru/g/elgf718etq31225e5a770e020ad620/?erid=LatgBUcjU"],
    ["image" : "Baggins",         "url"   : "https://aflink.ru/g/m33u5flihp31225e5a7787b20ecef3/?erid=LatgBgkRu"],
    ["image" : "Bestwatch",       "url"   : "https://aflink.ru/g/7d074b20eb31225e5a7777d7343c30/?erid=LatgBiNsP"]
    ]

struct ContentView: View {
    private let file = files.randomElement()!
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Реклама") {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: file["url"]!)!)
        }
        .buttonStyle(BunnerButton(img: Image(file["image"]!)))
    }
}

struct BunnerButton: ButtonStyle {
    let img: Image
   
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
        img
        .renderingMode(.original)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 38)
    }
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо. Все работает.

Comment: Еще раз здравствуйте. Появилась проблема. При вставке данного кода в новое представление (struct SecondView: View) при проверке в симуляторе загружается один и тотже баннер в обоих окнах. Как это исправить, чтобы при переходе из одного окна в другое как modal загружались разные баннеры.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Приведите ваш код, со слов непонятно, что не так работает.